# How to setup org-mouse to intuitively toggle checkboxes on org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I didn't find any documentation about that in anywhere. My personal setup which I use is [`prelude`](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude).

In the org-mode official documentation is pointed that:

> Every item in a plain list1 (see Plain lists) can be made into a checkbox by starting it with the string `[ ]`. This feature is similar to `TODO` items (see TODO items), but is more lightweight. Checkboxes are not included in the global TODO list, so they are often great to split a task into a number of simple steps. Or you can use them in a shopping list. To toggle a checkbox, use `C-c C-c`, or use the mouse (thanks to Piotr Zielinski's `org-mouse.el`). [Org-Mod Official Documentation Checkboxes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html)

But on my setup this doesn't work, for any of mouse buttons (1, 2, 3). I expected that `mouse-1` would work`, but it doesn't toogle the checkboxes when I click it. Do I need to set some special keybinding? I see that`org-mouse`is part of the standard extensions of Emacs... So I don't understand well how this works.

Comment: The official org-mode documentation is sometimes just weird.  Please file this as a bug, as pointed out already in a comment below the accepted answer.  While the section mentions the functionality, it gives zero pointers on how to activate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer on the file source -- I still think that this should be pointed on official docs of org-mode.

You need put `(require 'org-mouse)` on your `init.el` to enable this feature. If you don't desires reload your emacs, you just <kbd>`M-:` `(require 'org-mouse)` RET</kbd> <kbd>`M-x` `org-mode-restart` RET</kbd>.

Worked here.

Comment: "*I still think that this should be pointed on official docs of org-mode.*" -- Please consider filing a bug report / enhancement request.