# Org-mode, collapse/expand section on click

Tags: org-mode

Hi I'm on Linux and Emacs version is 26.3.

I would like to expand or collapse a block by mouse click, instead of moving the cursor to the header and press tab.

I actually have a windows computer does so, but do not work on my Linux one. I’ve tried to copy relevant files, however doesn’t work.

I also googled, but to be honest, cannot find where to start.

So if anyone can help? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `org-mouse` might help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34474/19819

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hubisan would you like to post and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **use the built-in org-mouse** which adds support for subtree expansion/collapsing (org-cycle) with the left mouse button.

To use it either

- add `(require 'org-mouse)` to your init file
- or activate it in the current session with <kbd>M-: (require 'org-mouse) RET M-x org-mode-restart RET</kbd>.

Org mouse implements the following features (taken from the package commentary):

```
;; * following links with the left mouse button
;; * subtree expansion/collapse (org-cycle) with the left mouse button
;; * several context menus on the right mouse button:
;;    + general text
;;    + headlines
;;    + timestamps
;;    + priorities
;;    + links
;;    + tags
;; * promoting/demoting/moving subtrees with mouse-3
;;    + if the drag starts and ends in the same line then promote/demote
;;    + otherwise move the subtree
```