# Org-mode: clickable heading

Tags: org-mode, mouse

I would like each org-mode section to be expandable with a left mouse click anywhere in the heading (excluding tags). [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55298/org-mode-collapse-expand-section-on-click) correctly points to `org-mouse`.

However, I must click on the section asterisks `*` to get the expansion behavior. The actual title is not clickable. For instance, if I want to display the content under the `* Heading` heading, clicking on the `*` expands the section, but clicking on `Heading` yields no result. The clickable area includes all asterisks (potentially more than one for sub-headings) and the single space between the asterisks and the heading. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you realize that hitting TAB anywhere on the heading expands it? Maybe that's enough and you don't need the mouse to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems promising

```lisp
(require 'org)
(defvar my-org-mouse-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(org-defkey my-org-mouse-map [mouse-1] 'org-cycle)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (defun my-org-mouse-map-hook ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords
             nil
             `((,(rx (and bol (one-or-more "*") (one-or-more space) (group-n 1 (one-or-more any)) eol))
                (0
                 `(
                   face nil
                   keymap ,my-org-mouse-map
                   mouse-face highlight
                   )
                 prepend)))
             t)))
```

`TAB` cycles across three states `FOLDED`, `CHILDREN`, and `SUBTREE`.

In the above `<mouse-1>` case above, it cycles between `FOLDED` and `CHILDREN`.

May be someone in the audience can refine the recipe for `mouse-1` case ...